# how to get every function, variable of every module that is install in system in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a code editor and I have created an autocomplete function for my code editor
but I am facing some problem because I want to get all modules name that is install and after importing any module all function, class, variable names of module that is imported
but I don't know how to do it
this is my code(not full code but short version of real one):

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import font
import re
def autoindent(event):
        global autocomplitition
        widget = event.widget
        index = widget.index(INSERT)
        index2 = "%s-%sc"%(index,1)
        word = widget.get(index2,index)
        line = widget.get("insert linestart", "insert lineend")

        match = re.match(r'^(\s+)', line)

        if word == ":":
            current_indent = len(match.group(0)) if match else 0
            
            
            new_indent = current_indent + 4
            
            widget.insert("insert", event.char + "\n" + " "*new_indent)
        elif autocomplitition == True:
            autocomplet_()
        else:
            whitespace = match.group(0) if match else ""

        
            widget.insert("insert", f"\n{whitespace}")


        return "break"
def autocomplet_(event=None):
    typed = editor.get("insert -1c wordstart","insert -1c wordend")
    editor.delete("insert -1c wordstart","insert -1c wordend")
    editor.insert("insert wordstart",autocomplet_list_box.selection_get())
    editor.focus_set()
    return "break"
def autcomplet(event=None):
    global autocomplitition
    typed = editor.get("insert -1c wordstart","insert -1c wordend")
    x,y,width,height = editor.bbox(INSERT)
    if typed == "":
        autocomplet_list_box.place_forget()
    else:
        data = []
        for i in list_:
            if typed in i:
                data.append(i)
        if len(data) == 1:
            autocomplet_list_box.place_configure(x=x,y=int(y+22),height=20)
            autocomplitition = True
        elif len(data) == 2:
            autocomplet_list_box.place_configure(x=x,y=int(y+22),height=40)
            autocomplitition = True
        elif len(data) == 3:
            autocomplet_list_box.place_configure(x=x,y=int(y+22),height=60)
            autocomplitition = True
        elif len(data) == 4:
            autocomplet_list_box.place_configure(x=x,y=int(y+22),height=80)
            autocomplitition = True
        elif len(data) == 5:
            autocomplet_list_box.place_configure(x=x,y=int(y+22),height=95)
            autocomplitition = True
        elif len(data) == 6:
            autocomplet_list_box.place_configure(x=x,y=int(y+22),height=110)
            autocomplitition = True
        elif len(data) == 7:
            autocomplet_list_box.place_configure(x=x,y=int(y+22),height=130)
            autocomplitition = True
        elif len(data) == 8:
            autocomplet_list_box.place_configure(x=x,y=int(y+22),height=150)
            autocomplitition = True
        elif len(data) == 9:
            autocomplet_list_box.place_configure(x=x,y=int(y+22),height=165)
            autocomplitition = True
        elif len(data) >= 10:
            autocomplet_list_box.place_configure(x=x,y=int(y+22),height=185)
            autocomplitition = True
        elif len(data) == 0:
            autocomplet_list_box.place_forget()
            autocomplitition = False
        autocomplet_list_box.delete(0,END)
        for i in data:
            autocomplet_list_box.insert(END,i)
        autocomplet_list_box.select_set(0)
def rbg(color):
        return "#%02x%02x%02x"%color
root = Tk()
list_ = ["and","as","assert","break","class","continue","def","del","elif","else","except","False","finally","for","from","global","if","import","in","is","lambda","None","nonlocal","not","or","pass","raise","return","True","try","while","with","yield",'abs', 'aiter', 'all', 'any', 'ascii', 'bin', 'bool', 'breakpoint', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 
'enumerate', 'eval', 'exec', 'exit', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'vars', 'zip'
,"self","__init__","__name__"
    # modules
    ,"tkinter","os","re","idlelib","colorizer","percolator","pygement","PyQt5"
       
    # tkinter
    ,'ACTIVE', 'ALL', 'ANCHOR', 'ARC', 'BASELINE', 'BEVEL', 'BOTH', 'BOTTOM', 'BROWSE', 'BUTT', 'BaseWidget', 'BitmapImage', 'BooleanVar', 'Button', 'CASCADE', 'CENTER', 'CHAR', 'CHECKBUTTON', 'CHORD', 'COMMAND', 'CURRENT', 'CallWrapper', 'Canvas', 'Checkbutton', 'DISABLED', 'DOTBOX', 'DoubleVar', 'E', 'END', 'EW', 'EXCEPTION', 'EXTENDED', 'Entry', 'Event', 'EventType', 'FALSE', 'FIRST', 'FLAT', 'Frame', 'GROOVE', 'Grid', 'HIDDEN', 'HORIZONTAL', 'INSERT', 'INSIDE', 'Image', 'IntVar', 'LAST', 'LEFT', 'Label', 'LabelFrame', 'Listbox', 'MITER', 'MOVETO', 'MULTIPLE', 'Menu', 'Menubutton', 'Message', 'Misc', 'N', 'NE', 'NO', 'NONE', 'NORMAL', 'NS', 'NSEW', 'NUMERIC', 'NW', 'NoDefaultRoot', 'OFF', 'ON', 'OUTSIDE', 'OptionMenu', 'PAGES', 'PIESLICE', 'PROJECTING', 'Pack', 'PanedWindow', 'PhotoImage', 'Place', 'RADIOBUTTON', 'RAISED', 'READABLE', 'RIDGE', 'RIGHT', 'ROUND', 'Radiobutton', 'S', 'SCROLL', 'SE', 'SEL', 'SEL_FIRST', 'SEL_LAST', 'SEPARATOR', 'SINGLE', 'SOLID', 'SUNKEN', 'SW', 'Scale', 'Scrollbar', 'Spinbox', 'StringVar', 'TOP', 'TRUE', 'Tcl', 'TclError', 'TclVersion', 'Text', 'Tk', 'TkVersion', 'Toplevel', 'UNDERLINE', 'UNITS', 'VERTICAL', 'Variable', 'W', 'WORD', 'WRITABLE', 'Widget', 'Wm', 'X', 'XView', 'Y', 'YES', 'YView', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_cnfmerge', '_default_root', '_destroy_temp_root', '_exit', '_flatten', '_get_default_root', '_get_temp_root', '_join', '_magic_re', '_setit', '_space_re', '_splitdict', '_stringify', '_support_default_root', '_test', '_tkerror', '_tkinter', '_varnum', 'constants', 'enum', 'getboolean', 'getdouble', 'getint', 'image_names', 'image_types', 'mainloop', 're', 'sys', 'types', 'wantobjects',

    #Tk
    '_Misc__winfo_getint', '_Misc__winfo_parseitem', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_bind', '_configure', '_displayof', '_getboolean', '_getconfigure', '_getconfigure1', '_getdoubles', '_getints', '_grid_configure', '_gridconvvalue', '_last_child_ids', '_loadtk', '_nametowidget', '_noarg_', '_options', '_register', '_report_exception', '_root', '_subst_format', '_subst_format_str', '_substitute', '_tclCommands', '_w', '_windowingsystem', 'after', 'after_cancel', 'after_idle', 'anchor', 'aspect', 'attributes', 'bbox', 'bell', 'bind', 
'bind_all', 'bind_class', 'bindtags', 'cget', 'client', 'clipboard_append', 'clipboard_clear', 'clipboard_get', 'colormapwindows', 'columnconfigure', 'command', 'config', 'configure', 'deiconify', 'deletecommand', 'destroy', 'event_add', 'event_delete', 'event_generate', 'event_info', 'focus', 'focus_displayof', 'focus_force', 'focus_get', 'focus_lastfor', 'focus_set', 'focusmodel', 'forget', 'frame', 'geometry', 'getboolean', 'getdouble', 'getint', 'getvar', 'grab_current', 'grab_release', 'grab_set', 'grab_set_global', 'grab_status', 'grid', 'grid_anchor', 'grid_bbox', 'grid_columnconfigure', 'grid_location', 'grid_propagate', 'grid_rowconfigure', 'grid_size', 'grid_slaves', 'group', 'iconbitmap', 'iconify', 'iconmask', 'iconname', 'iconphoto', 'iconposition', 'iconwindow', 'image_names', 'image_types', 'keys', 'lift', 'loadtk', 'lower', 'mainloop', 'manage', 'maxsize', 'minsize', 'nametowidget', 'option_add', 'option_clear', 'option_get', 'option_readfile', 'overrideredirect', 'pack_propagate', 'pack_slaves', 'place_slaves', 'positionfrom', 'propagate', 'protocol', 'quit', 'readprofile', 'register', 'report_callback_exception', 'resizable', 'rowconfigure', 'selection_clear', 'selection_get', 'selection_handle', 'selection_own', 'selection_own_get', 'send', 'setvar', 'size', 'sizefrom', 'slaves', 'state', 'title', 'tk_bisque', 'tk_focusFollowsMouse', 'tk_focusNext', 'tk_focusPrev', 'tk_setPalette', 'tk_strictMotif', 'tkraise', 'transient', 'unbind', 'unbind_all', 'unbind_class', 'update', 'update_idletasks', 'wait_variable', 'wait_visibility', 'wait_window', 'waitvar', 'winfo_atom', 'winfo_atomname', 'winfo_cells', 'winfo_children', 'winfo_class', 'winfo_colormapfull', 'winfo_containing', 'winfo_depth', 'winfo_exists', 'winfo_fpixels', 'winfo_geometry', 'winfo_height', 'winfo_id', 'winfo_interps', 'winfo_ismapped', 'winfo_manager', 'winfo_name', 'winfo_parent', 'winfo_pathname', 'winfo_pixels', 'winfo_pointerx', 'winfo_pointerxy', 'winfo_pointery', 'winfo_reqheight', 'winfo_reqwidth', 'winfo_rgb', 'winfo_rootx', 'winfo_rooty', 'winfo_screen', 'winfo_screencells', 'winfo_screendepth', 'winfo_screenheight', 'winfo_screenmmheight', 'winfo_screenmmwidth', 'winfo_screenvisual', 'winfo_screenwidth', 'winfo_server', 'winfo_toplevel', 'winfo_viewable', 'winfo_visual', 'winfo_visualid', 'winfo_visualsavailable', 'winfo_vrootheight', 'winfo_vrootwidth', 'winfo_vrootx', 'winfo_vrooty', 'winfo_width', 'winfo_x', 'winfo_y', 'withdraw', 'wm_aspect', 'wm_attributes', 'wm_client', 'wm_colormapwindows', 'wm_command', 'wm_deiconify', 'wm_focusmodel', 'wm_forget', 'wm_frame', 'wm_geometry', 'wm_grid', 'wm_group', 'wm_iconbitmap', 'wm_iconify', 'wm_iconmask', 'wm_iconname', 'wm_iconphoto', 'wm_iconposition', 'wm_iconwindow', 'wm_manage', 'wm_maxsize', 'wm_minsize', 'wm_overrideredirect', 'wm_positionfrom', 'wm_protocol', 'wm_resizable', 'wm_sizefrom', 'wm_state', 'wm_title', 'wm_transient', 'wm_withdraw',

# Label
'activebackground', 'activeforeground', 'anchor', 'background', 'bd', 'bg', 'bitmap', 'borderwidth', 'compound', 'cursor', 'disabledforeground', 'fg', 'font', 'foreground', 'height', 'highlightbackground', 'highlightcolor', 'highlightthickness', 'image', 'justify', 'padx', 'pady', 'relief', 'state', 'takefocus', 'text', 'textvariable', 'underline', 'width', 'wraplength',

#Frame
 'colormap', 'container', 'takefocus', 'visual',
 
 #Text
 'autoseparators', 'blockcursor', 'borderwidth', 'endline', 'exportselection', 'inactiveselectbackground', 'insertbackground', 'insertborderwidth', 'insertofftime', 'insertontime', 'insertunfocussed', 'insertwidth', 'maxundo', 'selectbackground', 'selectborderwidth', 'selectforeground', 'setgrid', 'spacing1', 'spacing2', 'spacing3', 'startline', 'state', 'tabs', 'tabstyle', 'takefocus', 'undo', 'wrap', 'xscrollcommand', 'yscrollcommand',
                
# command
'_Misc__winfo_getint', '_Misc__winfo_parseitem', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_bind', '_configure', '_displayof', '_do', '_getboolean', '_getconfigure', '_getconfigure1', '_getdoubles', '_getints', '_grid_configure', '_gridconvvalue', '_last_child_ids', '_name', '_nametowidget', '_noarg_', '_options', '_register', '_report_exception', '_root', '_setup', '_subst_format', '_subst_format_str', '_substitute', '_tclCommands', '_w', '_windowingsystem', 'after', 'after_cancel', 'after_idle', 'anchor', 'bbox', 'bell', 'bind', 'bind_all', 'bind_class', 'bindtags', 'cget', 'children', 'clipboard_append', 'clipboard_clear', 'clipboard_get', 'columnconfigure', 'compare', 'config', 'configure', 'count', 'debug', 'delete', 'deletecommand', 'destroy', 'dlineinfo', 'dump', 'edit', 'edit_modified', 'edit_redo', 'edit_reset', 'edit_separator', 'edit_undo', 'event_add', 'event_delete', 'event_generate', 'event_info', 'focus', 'focus_displayof', 'focus_force', 'focus_get', 'focus_lastfor', 'focus_set', 'forget', 'get', 'getboolean', 'getdouble', 'getint', 'getvar', 'grab_current', 'grab_release', 'grab_set', 'grab_set_global', 'grab_status', 'grid', 'grid_anchor', 'grid_bbox', 'grid_columnconfigure', 'grid_configure', 'grid_forget', 'grid_info', 'grid_location', 'grid_propagate', 'grid_remove', 'grid_rowconfigure', 'grid_size', 'grid_slaves', 'image_cget', 'image_configure', 'image_create', 'image_names', 'image_types', 'index', 'info', 'insert', 'keys', 'lift', 'location', 'lower', 'mainloop', 'mark_gravity', 'mark_names', 'mark_next', 'mark_previous', 'mark_set', 'mark_unset', 'master', 'nametowidget', 'option_add', 'option_clear', 'option_get', 'option_readfile', 'pack', 'pack_configure', 'pack_forget', 'pack_info', 'pack_propagate', 'pack_slaves', 'peer_create', 'peer_names', 'place', 'place_configure', 'place_forget', 'place_info', 'place_slaves', 'propagate', 'quit', 'register', 'replace', 'rowconfigure', 'scan_dragto', 'scan_mark', 'search', 'see', 'selection_clear', 'selection_get', 'selection_handle', 'selection_own', 'selection_own_get', 'send', 'setvar', 'size', 'slaves', 'tag_add', 'tag_bind', 'tag_cget', 'tag_config', 'tag_configure', 'tag_delete', 'tag_lower', 'tag_names', 'tag_nextrange', 'tag_prevrange', 'tag_raise', 'tag_ranges', 'tag_remove', 'tag_unbind', 'tk', 'tk_bisque', 'tk_focusFollowsMouse', 
'tk_focusNext', 'tk_focusPrev', 'tk_setPalette', 'tk_strictMotif', 'tkraise', 'unbind', 'unbind_all', 'unbind_class', 'update', 'update_idletasks', 'wait_variable', 'wait_visibility', 'wait_window', 'waitvar', 'widgetName', 'window_cget', 'window_config', 'window_configure', 'window_create', 'window_names', 'winfo_atom', 'winfo_atomname', 'winfo_cells', 'winfo_children', 'winfo_class', 'winfo_colormapfull', 'winfo_containing', 'winfo_depth', 'winfo_exists', 'winfo_fpixels', 'winfo_geometry', 'winfo_height', 'winfo_id', 'winfo_interps', 'winfo_ismapped', 'winfo_manager', 'winfo_name', 'winfo_parent', 'winfo_pathname', 'winfo_pixels', 'winfo_pointerx', 'winfo_pointerxy', 'winfo_pointery', 'winfo_reqheight', 'winfo_reqwidth', 'winfo_rgb', 'winfo_rootx', 'winfo_rooty', 'winfo_screen', 'winfo_screencells', 'winfo_screendepth', 'winfo_screenheight', 'winfo_screenmmheight', 'winfo_screenmmwidth', 'winfo_screenvisual', 'winfo_screenwidth', 'winfo_server', 'winfo_toplevel', 'winfo_viewable', 'winfo_visual', 'winfo_visualid', 'winfo_visualsavailable', 'winfo_vrootheight', 'winfo_vrootwidth', 'winfo_vrootx', 'winfo_vrooty', 'winfo_width', 'winfo_x', 'winfo_y', 'xview', 'xview_moveto', 'xview_scroll', 'yview', 'yview_moveto', 'yview_pickplace', 
'yview_scroll'
                ]
autocomplititon = False
TAB = 4
textfont = font.Font(family = "JetBrains Mono", size = 15)
indent = TAB * textfont.measure("M")
editor =Text(
    root,height=20,
    font = textfont,
    tabs = indent,bg=rbg((14,16,26)),fg="white",insertbackground="white",undo=True,borderwidth=0)
autocomplet_list_box = Listbox(editor,font=("JetBrains Mono",10),bg=rbg((10,11,16)),fg="white",selectbackground=rbg((20,22,32)),selectforeground="white")

editor.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)




editor.bind("<Return>",autoindent)
editor.bind("<KeyRelease>",autcomplet)





root.mainloop()
```

this is what I am creating:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is not the way you write function.  It doesn't anything to display in textbox.

Correct way to write function. Added `insert` and `delete`

In line 32, change this:

```
def autocomplet_(event=None):
    typed = editor.get("insert -1c wordstart","insert -1c wordend")
    editor.delete("insert -1c wordstart","insert -1c wordend")
    editor.insert("insert wordstart",autocomplet_list_box.selection_get())
    editor.focus_set()
    return "break"
```

to:

```
def autocomplet_(event=None):
    #editor.delete('1.0', 'end')
    selected_indices = autocomplet_list_box.curselection()    
    selected_langs = ",".join([autocomplet_list_box.get(i) for i in selected_indices])
    editor.insert('end', selected_langs[1:])
    editor.focus_set()
    return "break"
```

Screenshot:

[image]